# Identify and duplicate unique rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have files of data with the following format:

[image]

In column A, identifiers occur either doubly (e.g. 302_60) or singularly (e.g.310_58). Additional information is present in column B.

What I want to do is:

1. tag the rows that have single identifiers in column A with
   TRUE/FALSE in Column C
2. for any TRUE tag, insert a line BELOW
3. copy into the inserted row the contents of the ENTIRE tagged row (here just columns A,B)

I solved #1 using =COUNTIF(A:A, A1)=1

[image]

I then wrote a VBA script to solve #2

```
Sub ins_below_and_copy()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("C1:C100")
If InStr(1, c, "TRUE", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Rows(c.Offset(1, 0).Row & ":" & c.Offset(1, 0).Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown
End If
Next c
End Sub
```

[image]

Achieving the desired end result (#3)

[image]

seems simple enough, right? I have been trying .Copy and .Paste commands, but keep getting type-mismatch errors, an error that does not make sense to me (since I am not a competent VBA coder). Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of copying and pasting, why not loop through the cells and for each blank cell, make that cell equal to the one above it?

Answer (score 0):

You have down all the hard work, filling in the gaps is easy. Select the two columns, HOME > Editing - Find & Select, Go To Special..., Blanks, OK, `=`, UP and Ctrl+Enter.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this after you have your empty rows created.

```
Dim sheet As String
Dim lastRow As Long

sheet = "SheetName"
lastRow = Sheets(sheet).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For r = 2 To lastRow   'Assuming you have a Header Row
    If Sheets(sheet).Cells(r, 1) = "" Then
        Sheets(sheet).Cells(r - 1, 3) = "FALSE"
        Sheets(sheet).Cells(r, 1) = Sheets(sheet).Cells(r - 1, 1)
        Sheets(sheet).Cells(r, 2) = Sheets(sheet).Cells(r - 1, 2)
        Sheets(sheet).Cells(r, 3) = Sheets(sheet).Cells(r - 1, 3)
    End If
Next r
```